# minimizing log likelihood to find the parameters for my heston nandi model using python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, finance, numerical-methods

I have an objective function which I would like to use MLE to find the parameters for my model.This is my code so far.Also my returnarr is an array of log returns of the stock
Here is the first 30 values of my returnarr just for reference:

```
returnarr = filterdata['logreturn'].to_numpy(dtype=np.longdouble)
returnarr[0:30]
```

```
array([ 0.00075018, -0.00696353, -0.00080357,  0.00287779, -0.00384807,
       -0.00496853,  0.00608317, -0.00252242, -0.00731938,  0.01879965,
       -0.00673696, -0.00757294, -0.02209292,  0.01152935,  0.00609485,
        0.004072  , -0.01832714, -0.01604845,  0.0059958 ,  0.00251289,
        0.00740885, -0.01594026,  0.0076436 , -0.00298763,  0.00460656,
       -0.00237508,  0.0078305 ,  0.003722  ,  0.00649657])
```

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# Define the log-likelihood function
def log_likelihood(parameters,returnarr):
    size=len(returnarr)
    phi = parameters[0]
    w = parameters[1]
    B = parameters[2]
    alpha = parameters[3]
    lambda1=parameters[4]
    epsilon = np.zeros(size, dtype='longdouble')
    variance = np.zeros(size + 1, dtype='longdouble')
    variance[0]=0.001

    for x,val in  enumerate(returnarr):
        epsilon[x] = (val - (rate + (lambda1 * variance[x]))) / np.sqrt(variance[x])
        variance[x+1] = w + (B * variance[x]) + (alpha * np.square(epsilon[x]-(phi*np.sqrt(variance[x]))))
        
    variance=variance[:-1]#remove last term
    log_likelihood_on_return = -0.5 * np.sum(np.log(variance) +np.square(epsilon))
    return log_likelihood_on_return  # Minimize the negative log-likelihood
```

Any suggestion for how I could use minimize to find the parameters here?

I've tried this:

```py
initial_parameters=[0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01]
bounds = [(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1)]

result = minimize(log_likelihood, initial_parameters, args=(returnarr,),bounds=bounds)
```

I still get errors which say

````
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  variance[x+1] = w + (B * variance[x]) + (alpha * np.square(epsilon[x]-(phi*np.sqrt(variance[x]))))
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  epsilon[x] = (val - (rate + (lambda1 * variance[x]))) / np.sqrt(variance[x])```
````

Comment: By your phrasing it seems like you're already aware of the existence of [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html), is your question how to use it?

Comment: Yes my questions on how to use the minimize function in my case.When i use it  initial_parameters=[0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01]                                                                                              `result = minimize(log_likelihood, initial_parameters, args=(returnarr,),method='L-BFGS-B')
it gives me an error:RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  variance[x+1] = w + (B * variance[x]) + (alpha * np.square(epsilon[x]-(phi*np.sqrt(variance[x])))) .That is why i was unsure of my implementation of this method

Comment: Can you provide definitions for `rate` and `returnarr`?

Comment: You might consider setting the `bounds` argument in `optimize` to ensure the guesses aren't getting too far out of hand. For the method you're using look at [these options](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-lbfgsb.html#optimize-minimize-lbfgsb) to see about getting more information about what's happening, setting step sizes and the like

Comment: @NickODell The rate is the interest rate used in this problem which is 2.47% and the return array consists of 1510  log-returns of the stock data.

Comment: @AJBiffl I have updated the question to give more insight on my returnarr.I tried the problem with bounds set but it still seems to give me issues

Comment: It appears your likelihood is a monotonically decreasing function of all of your parameters, at least over the range of parameters where you don't get overflow. Double check your likelihood, and if it's correct consider re-expressing so you don't get overflow (calculate the log of the log or something). It's also possible that you've just guessed poorly, and there's a valley somewhere that's hard to spot, so you can try randomly generating a lot of guesses - but double check everything is correct first.

Comment: [This](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/53014/problem-with-the-maximum-likelihood-for-a-garch-type-of-model) might also be helpful